# Reloading logbook configuration when running in Akka

Tags: logging, akka, logback

I am using the [logback-classic](https://logback.qos.ch) in an akka project.  Logback
has a setting related to refreshing its configuration from the config
file, i.e. setting `<configuration  scan="true" scanPeriod="10
seconds">` in the XML config file, should reload the settings every 10
seconds.  This functionality seems to be broken when running as an Akka
logging backend because the changes in the config file are propagated only on
restart of the Akka processes.  Is there a way to force the reload
behavior somehow?